# FFmpeg: crossfading audio with multiple files, but works with video only

Tags: linux, bash, audio, video, ffmpeg

I've found this script that cross-fade's all mp4's in the directory. If I try to add the audio with `AUDIO="[0:a]afade=d=1[a0];"`, using the same iteration, it doesn't work.

This works fine...

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CMD="ffmpeg"
FILES=(*.mp4)
SIZE=${#FILES[@]}
VIDEO=""
OUT=""

i="0"
total_duration="0"
for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
  echo "$file"
  CMD="$CMD -i '$file'"

  duration=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of csv=p=0 "$file" | cut -d'.' -f1)

  if [[ "$i" == "0" ]]
  then
    VIDEO="[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];"
  else
    fade_start=$((total_duration))
    VIDEO="${VIDEO}[${i}:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(${fade_start}/TB)[v${i}];"
    if (( i < SIZE-1 ))
    then
      if (( i == 1 ))
      then
        OUT="${OUT}[v0][v1]overlay[outv1];"
      else
        OUT="${OUT}[outv$((i-1))][v${i}]overlay[outv${i}];"
      fi
    else
      if (( SIZE == 2 ))
      then
        OUT="${OUT}[v0][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[outv]"
      else
        OUT="${OUT}[outv$((i-1))][v${i}]overlay,format=yuv420p[outv]"
      fi
    fi
  fi

  total_duration=$((total_duration+duration))

  i=$((i+1))
done

CMD="$CMD -filter_complex \"${VIDEO}${OUT}\" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -map [outv] crossfade.mp4"

echo "$CMD"

bash -c "$CMD"
```

I read `acrossfade` requires 32bit little endian, so I went to `afade`.
It didn't change anything.

I've got this working via fade in/out, for any number of files, with working audio. I still have to preprocess the audio sections which require fading.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e *.mkv ]; then
  file_type=".mkv"
else
  file_type=".mp4"
fi

mkdir ./temp
for file in *$file_type; do mv "$file" "in_$file"; done

# Function to fade in video
function fade_in() {
file_list1=(in_*)
  echo "Executing fade_in"
  for file in "${file_list1[@]}"; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -y -vf fade=in:0:30 -hide_banner -preset ultrafast "out_$file"
  done
mv in_* ./temp
}
export -f fade_in

# Function to fade out video
function fade_out() {
  file_list2=(out_*)
  echo "Executing fade_out"
  for file in "${file_list2[@]}"; do
    frame_count=$(ffmpeg -i $file -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'frame= *[0-9]+ *' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1)
      frame_start=$((frame_count - 30))
      ffmpeg -i "$file" -y -vf fade=out:"$frame_start":30 -hide_banner -preset ultrafast "to_mux_$file"
  done
  mv out_* ./temp
}

export -f fade_out

bash -c "fade_in"
bash -c "fade_out"

ls --quoting-style=shell-always -1v *$file_type > tmp.txt
sed 's/^/file /' tmp.txt > list.txt && rm tmp.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy -shortest -movflags +faststart fade_muxed$file_type

mv to_mux_* ./temp
rm list.txt
#rm -rf ./temp

exit 0
```

Number the file name's sequentially **(i.e. 01_file.mkv 02_file.mkv etc.)**, to ensure order, or it will be up to the directory sort. Using `ls --quoting-style=shell-always -v1` has proved very reliable. It should handle 99% of naming conventions.
It's not a cross fade, but the two second transition is very close. With **working and synchronized** audio.
If you have a good multi-file concatenation method that includes audio cross-fading, I'm still looking.

*Ed Morton, I completely agree, sir. One-hundred percent. I didn't write the first script. I would NEVER use capitals. They're horrible. I `"like_full_words"` with `_`'s. Never for any reason other than visual though, so that was [a great read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization), I recommend it.*

Comment: Are you trying to concat at the end?  For 3 inputs, it should look like this: `[v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"`

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and then fix your variable names. Your problem could be caused by you clobbering some environment variable for all we know so there's no point looking into it further til that isn't a consideration.

Comment: As a general point though - don't store a command and arguments in a string to execute later, use an array if you need to build it up dynamically, see #5 in particular at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: If either of those points are so critical, why does video by itself work flawlessly?

Comment: That variable naming convention thread was cool, right on.  I'm picking up what you're putting down.  Though, it further convinced me the functionality is not being affected.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.