# Faster way to generate exact time segments with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am in the need of creating exact seconds segments of a video

Currently I am using this command (Javascript string) where I read from a folder multiple videos
`segmentLenght` is usually obtained through computations, so its value is a float like `1.66666` or `1.5` seconds or even whole numbers like `2`

`ffmpeg -hide_banner  -err_detect ignore_err -i "${inputFolder + '/' + video}" -r 24 -codec:v libx264  -vsync 1  -codec:a aac  -ac 2  -ar 48k  -f segment   -preset fast  -segment_format mpegts  -segment_time ${segmentLenght} -force_key_frames  "expr: gte(t, n_forced * ${segmentLenght})" "${outputFolder + '/' + video.split('.')[0] + '_%d.' + ext}"`

This command works almost as expected, it generates segments exactly with the segmentLenght I give it (some few milliseconds of error, I'm guessing from the float number of seconds)

The problem is that it takes a very long time to process these segments. Do you know a faster way for the same result?

Comment: Frames.  Use frame count.  `ffmpeg -i $file -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'frame= *[0-9]+ *' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not very familiar with ffmpeg syntax. Can you tell me where exactly in this command is the actual segment length in seconds?

Comment: Change `-preset` to `ultrafast`

Answer (score 0):

This will output the frame number for a video.

```
ffmpeg -i your_file.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'frame= *[0-9]+ *' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1
```

Like this:
[image]

This video is 400 frames.

This would be an example of how to incorporate it into a script.

```bash
  for file in "${file_list2[@]}"; do
    frame_count=$(ffmpeg -i $file -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'frame= *[0-9]+ *' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1)
      frame_start=$((frame_count - 30))
      ffmpeg -i "$file" -y -vf fade=out:"$frame_start":30 -hide_banner -preset ultrafast "to_mux_$file"
  done
```

This is an excerpt [from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420030/ffmpeg-crossfading-audio-with-multiple-files-but-works-with-video-only) that merges all the videos in the directory with fade in/out effect.  I had to use frames to make this work properly and, subsequently, where I grabbed the code from.